In one of the cshtml files,namespaces can not be found
I am using visual studio 2022 .net 6. All the other cshtml files within the same project are not showing any issues. Only in one cshtml file, the namespaces are not able to be found. All the namespaces are already added in using statement. Also, the values in a string inside the html tag are being recognized falsely as namespaces by visual studio. I have tried deleting obj and bin folder are rebuilding. I also tried removing and adding the package references.

I have tried deleting obj and bin folder are rebuilding.
I also tried removing and adding the package references.


I met similar issue before, and in my side it's usually caused by typo or some wrong coding. Could you please try to comment  some parts of the codes and try to narrow down the issue? Or could you please share the problematic cshtml file content for troubelshooting?

for eg: part of the string parameter in actionButton is taken as a namespace.

could you pls provide any screenshot and the code snippet?

 Error: The type or namespace name 'Download' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Do you think it's enough for community member to understand what occurred in your VS?
